# Exporting TASKLET in kernel module?

Tags: module, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, symbol-table

I got two kernel modules which both exports some symbols using EXPORT_SYMBOL().
One of them exports basic function (sv1<-sv2) and it works but I got problem with the other one (sv1->sv2).

What I want is to export **TASKLET**. I read somewhere that is possibile and there is no proscription of doing this. Module nr 1 (called *sv1*) consists of *BH Function* and declaration of tasklet:

```
struct tasklet_struct sv_takslet;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(sv_takslet);

void sv_tasklet_function( unsigned long data )
{
  printk( "%s\n", (char *)data );
  return;
}

static int __init sv_publisher_init(void)
{
...
tasklet_init(&sv_takslet, &sv_tasklet_function,&sv_tasklet_data);
...
}
```

In second module there is global reference and *task_schedule()* function used at initialization of the module nr 2 (called *sv2*):

```
extern struct tasklet_struct sv_takslet;
... 
tasklet_schedule(&sv_takslet);
```

The problem is when I got:

```
tasklet_schedule(&sv_takslet);
```

in my code **I do not see my two modules on list** (*modprobe -l*), but when I comment this line on *sv2*- they magically appear.

What could be a cause of that behavior? Is this initialization is correct?

---

**EDIT**

The cause of this problem is that module *sv2* is loading before *sv1* and has no knowledge about the tasklet (line: extern struct tasklet_struct sv_takslet). When I change destination that *sv2* exports **TASKLET** to *sv1* the problem is gone.

But now I am facing with that **both modules have to export symbols to each other**. I have no idea how to solve this problem...

Both *.c files are in the same directory and my Makefile has following line:

```
obj-m += sv_publisher.o zsv_core.o
```

Does anybody have some tips how to go about it?

Comment: `What could be a cause of that behavior?` - **Almost any incorrect operation** in the kernel space can lead to data corruption of other object. Your usage pattern of tasklet seems to be correct. EXPORT_SYMBOL has nothing common with the problem. The fact, that eliminating some operation clears observable error doesn't mean that other operations are correct. Try to debug other parts of your modules.

Comment: `both modules have to export symbols to each other.` You cannot load modules with circular dependencies. You'll have to change it so that one module "registers" (and "deregisters") some interface (e.g. a struct containing data and function pointers) with the other module.